# is it possible to install python on windows RT?

Tags: python

I would like to install and run python on windows RT. Is it possible?
I have tried with python.org but it doesn't seem to have a specific version for it. I wonder whether there is anything I could use instead?

Comment: I see this: http://www.windows-arm.com/index.php/desktop-apps-for-windows-rt/706-python-for-windows-rt

Answer (score 0):

Portable Python and Python (x,y) both work on RT